# Is it possible to make Decompose work with coefficients containing radicals?

Tags: programming, symbolic, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

It appears that [`Decompose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Decompose.html) works reliably only on polynomials with integer coefficients, although it seems to be not mentioned in the docs. Can I make it work (or implement an alternative that would work) on polynomials with coefficients containing radicals? For example,

```
Decompose[3 + 3 √2 + (14 + 4 √2) x + (12 + 26 √2) x^2 + 
    (56 + 8 √2) x^3 + (8 + 48 √2) x^4 + 48 x^5 + 16 √2 x^6, x]

(* {3 + 3 √2 + (14 + 4 √2) x + (4 + 12 √2) x^2 + 8 x^3, x + √2 x^2} *)
```

Is there a known algorithmic solution to this problem at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to decompose a polynomial $p(x)$ is to factor $p'(x)$ over a field and exploit $\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

The following code does just that to find all candidate $g'(x)$:

```
extendedDecompose[poly_, x_, extension_:Automatic] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] := 
  Module[{ext, res},
    ext = If[extension === Automatic, CoefficientList[poly, x], extension];

    res = FixedPoint[
      Flatten[Prepend[Rest[#], iExtendedDecompose[First[#], x, ext]]]&,
      {poly}
    ];
    res = res //. {a___, x^n_., x^m_., b___} :> {a, x^(n + m), b};

    simplifyCoefficients[res, x]
  ]

extendedDecompose[expr_, ___] := {expr}

iExtendedDecompose[poly_, x_, extension_] :=
  Module[{deg, facs, cands, dg, d, a, gcoeffs, f, g, sys, sol, res},
    deg = Exponent[poly, x];
    If[deg <= 1 || PrimeQ[deg], Return[{poly}]];

    facs = Select[FactorList[D[poly, x], Extension -> extension], Exponent[#[[1]], x] > 0&];
    If[Length[facs] < 2, Return[{poly}]];

    cands = Select[Times @@@ Subsets[Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ facs], 1 <= Exponent[#, x] <= 0.5deg&];

    SetAttributes[a, Listable];
    Catch[
      Do[
        dg = Exponent[gprime, x]+1;
        d = deg/dg;
        f = fromCoefficients[a[Range[0, d]], x];

        gcoeffs = Prepend[CoefficientList[gprime, x]/Range[dg], 0];
        gcoeffs /= SelectFirst[gcoeffs, Not @* PossibleZeroQ];
        g = fromCoefficients[gcoeffs, x];

        sys = Thread[CoefficientList[Expand[f /. x -> g] - poly, x] == 0];
        sol = Solve[sys, a[Range[0, d]]];

        If[ListQ[sol] && Length[sol] > 0,
          Throw[{f /. First[sol], g}]
        ],
        {gprime, cands}
      ];

      {poly}
    ]
  ]

SetAttributes[simplifyCoefficients, Listable];

simplifyCoefficients[poly_, x_] := 
  fromCoefficients[Simplify[CoefficientList[poly, x]], x]

fromCoefficients[coeffs_, x_] := coeffs . PowerRange[1, x^(Length[coeffs] - 1), x]
```

Your example:

```
poly = 3 + 3 √2 + (14 + 4 √2) x + (12 + 26 √2) x^2 + 
  (56 + 8 √2) x^3 + (8 + 48 √2) x^4 + 48 x^5 + 16 √2 x^6;

decomp = extendedDecompose[poly, x]
```

> ```
> {3 (1 + √2) + (14 + 4 √2) x + (4 + 12 √2) x^2 + 8 x^3, x + √2 x^2}
> ```

```
PossibleZeroQ[poly - (First[decomp] /. x -> Last[decomp])]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

A nested example:

```
poly2 = Collect[poly /. x -> x^4 - x + 1, x];

decomp2 = extendedDecompose[poly2, x]
```

> ```
> {3 (47 + 35 √2) + (-478 - 368 √2) x + (540 + 436 √2) x^2 - 8 (25 + 22 √2) x^3, 
>     x - (2 x^2)/(4 + √2), x - x^4}
> ```

```
Fold[#1 /. x -> #2 &, decomp2] - poly2 // PossibleZeroQ
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: This is also the method used by `Decompose` (due to Alagar and Tranh if I remember correctly). It was implemented well before the `Extension` option in `Factor` and we never really revisited it.